# Implement Dijkstra's Algorithm with a d-ary heap

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, dijkstra, asymptotic-complexity

As you can see in this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap#Applications
It says in Wikipedia that the optimal choice of d is d=m/n (it leads to a total time complexity of O(m logm/n n) )

It seems to me that this guess was pulled out of thin air. Is there a simple way of proving (or even explaining) that this is indeed the optimal d ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the explanation itself you can deduct that you have n delete min operations each requiring `O(d log(n)/log(d))` and m decrease priority operations of `O(log(n)/log(d))`. The combined work is then `(m*log(n)+n*d*log(n))/log(d)`.

If you fill in the suggested d value, the global behavior is as stated `O(m*log(n)/log(d))`. If you take any other d, one of the terms is bigger then the average, resulting in an increased complexity.